# Is it possible to have a mapping for Angular model property names?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, restangular

I'm currently working on an app whose database schema changes frequently. This rapid change creates a big problem for my front-end Angular code which consumes the backend JSON API (which I don't have much control over) via Restangular; take the following code for example:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <h2>{{item.label}}</h2>
    </li>
</ul>
```

There will be a lot of template tags like `{{item.label}}` scattered everywhere in the front-end code, so whenever the property name changes from, say "label" to "item_label", I'll need to remember where those tags are and change all of them. Of course, I could do a project wide search and replace, but that's not really ideal from an DRY stand point and it'll also be a maintenance nightmare.

My question is, does Angular (or Restangular) provide a way to map model property names to custom ones like [this in Backbone?](https://engineering.groupon.com/2012/javascript/extending-backbone-js-to-map-rough-api-responses-into-beautiful-client-side-models/)

That way, I can just have something like this

```
{
    label: model.item_label
}
```

then next time when the "item_label" is changed to something else, I can just update it in this configuration object and not worry about all the references in the templates.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The idea with angular is that you can do whatever you want with the model. While this doesn't point you in any specific direction it does give you the opportunity to implement it in your own OO manner. Say you have an app that has a data object called ...`Task` a model for tasks might look like..

```
function Task(initJson){
    this.name = initJson._name || 'New Task';
    this.completed = initJson.is_completed || false;
    this.doneDateTime = initJson.datetime || null;        
}

Task.prototype = {
    save: function(){
        //do stuff with this and $http.put/post...        
    }
    create: function(){
        //do stuff with this and $http.put/post
    }
    //....etc
}
```

All of this might be wrapped up in a factory.

```
myApp.factory('TaskFactory',function($http){
    var Tasks = []; //Or {};

    //above constructor function...
    //other helper methods...etc



    return {
        instance: Task,
        collection: Tasks,            
        init: function(){} // get all tasks? run them through the constructor (Task), populate collection
    };
})
```

You could then edit properties on your constructor (one place (for each data type), the only place). Although this isn't ideal if your using things like Restangular or $resource as they not equipped to be a large backing store but they just assume the properties that come across the wire, which for large, changing applications can sometimes be difficult to manage.

Comment: Thanks a lot, calebboyd! This does sound like a great solution. However, as you mentioned above, it is not really ideal for larger projects. Please see my answer on the solution I ended up going with.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with Restangular's `setResponseExtractor` config property based on [this FAQ answer](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#how-can-i-access-the-unrestangularized-element-as-well-as-the-restangularized-one).

It looks like this:

```
Restangular.setResponseExtractor(function(response, operation, what, url) {
    var newResponse = response;
    angular.forEach(newResponse.items, function(item) {
        item.label = item.item_label;
    }
    return newResponse;
}
```